# Update UI from a broadcast receiver registered in the manifest

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have this problem that I'm registering my Broadcast receiver for AlarmManager in the manifest. And I'm scheduling it in my Activity through pending Intent.

```
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent =PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(this, AlarmReciever.class),PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, Constants.ALARM_TRIGGER_AT_TIME,Constants.ALARM_INTERVAL, pendingIntent);
```

But in my receiver class I'm doing some network updates using AlarmManager...which I'm saving in a database. I have a ListAdapter in the activity and need to notifydatasetChanged...for which I need an instance of my activity.

How to get it? Basically I want to update my UI at least when my app is visible.

Comment: you have passed  AlarmReciever.class as a instance use it.

Comment: No i want the instance of my activity on my broadcast reciever class..Actually i tried using Inner class in activity itself but its not working...I think Manifest is not supporting a innner class path or something????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer..For refreshing my activity which is visible

```
        Intent i=new Intent(caller,Dot.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        caller.startActivity(i);
```

If activity visible it will call the OnNewIntent() in your code and thus onResume() where you can update Your UI..

Answer (score 1):

create a `BroadcastReceiver` in your activity, register it inside the `onResume` of your activity and unregister it in `onPause` .After completing the network update , create an `Intent`, put in all the data that you want to send to your activity and fire it.If your activity is in foreground then only it will receive this intent.From `onReceive()` of `BroadcaseReceiver` in your activity you can get all the data and then update the Ui.

create a `BroadcastReceiver` In your Activity ::

```
 private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

             /////// update your UI from here ////////     
            }

}
```

Inside `onCreate()`, create an instance of this receiver ::

```
myReceiver=new MyReceiver();
```

Register this receiver from `OnResume()` ::

```
    IntentFilter filter=new IntentFilter();
    filter.setPriority(1);
    filter.addAction( "MyPackageName.MyAction" );
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
```

unreigister it in `onPause()` ::

```
unregisterReceiver( myReceiver );
```

Now, Fire  an intent after completing network update fire an intent to start this receiver ::

```
            Intent broadcastIntent=new Intent();
            broadcastIntent.setAction( "MyPackageName.MyAction" );
            broadcastIntent.putExtra();// put data to send to your activity
            sendBroadcast( broadcastIntent );
```

Comment: I dont know Why but registering thru a activity the broadcast onRecieve is not getting called itself....Can u help me with that...do i need to do something else??

Comment: @sheetal, action set in filter.setAction() and the one used while firing the intent in broadcastIntent.setAction must match, and action should of the form packageName.MyAction.eg::filter.addAction("com.ap.myApp.myAction");

Comment: any idea how can update existing UI screen...just want to update status on screen for received broadcast.